# Virtual Qt signal?

Tags: c++, qt

Whilst reviewing some Qt C++ code I came across this:

```
class Foo
{
  Q_OBJECT

signals:
  virtual void someSignal(const QString& str, int n)
  {
    Q_UNUSED(str);
    Q_UNUSED(n);
  }
  ...
};
```

Now, Qt signals cannot have a body so I'm surprised this even compiles (perhaps because the body is effectively empty).  I also don't see the point of making a signal virtual as ... it can't have a body so how can it be overridden?

Am I missing something here or is this a valid code smell?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That looks smelly to me.

It's valid to declare a signal in a base class and then emit it from a derived class, e.g.

```
class MyBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
// ...
signals:
    void somethingHappened();
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    Q_OBJECT
// ...
    void doSomething();
};

void MyDerived::doSomething()
{
    // ....
    emit somethingHappened();
}
```

Maybe that's what the declaration in the question was meant to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly C++ speaking it's normal it compiles, given `signal` is a macro for `protected` and `Q_UNUSED` is a cast to `void`.
But you should get an error when running `moc` which precisely creates the implementation of the methods declared as signals.

Comment: It may compile, but it is still an ODR violation: the function has two bodies, one in the header and one in the cpp emitted by the moc.

Answer (score 3):

Qt signals are not allowed to be (pure) virtual. See comments to this bug - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41004

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: I don't know what the code was meant to do, but it's wrong (not merely smelling wrong, it's prima facie invalid). Signal implementations are **always** meant to be generated by moc. The body of the signal should be removed.

1. For the code to work, it should do all three: compile, get past moc, and link. It is true that your code does compile - the C++ compiler has no reason not to. But it won't pass through moc nor will it link.
2. Although perhaps *moc* didn't detect some of it back in 2010, here's how *moc* acts today:

   a) *moc* doesn't allow signal definitions in class bodies, with the diagnostic `Error: Not a signal declaration`. So `class X { Q_SIGNAL void s() {} };` triggers it, but `class X { Q_SIGNAL void s(); }; void X::s() {}` won't.

   b) *moc* doesn't allow a `Q_OBJECT` macro in a class not deriving from `QObject`, with the diagnostic `Error: Class contains Q_OBJECT macro but does not inherit from QObject`.
3. Since it doesn't make any sense to talk about signals in classes that don't derive from `QObject`, let's assume that the code really looked as follows:

   ```
   class Foo : public QObject
   {
     Q_OBJECT
   signals:
     virtual void someSignal(const QString&, int);
   };
   void Foo::someSignal(const QString& str, int n)
   {
     Q_UNUSED(str);
     Q_UNUSED(n);
   }
   ```

   This will get past moc and will compile, but it won't link. The linker will issue a diagnostic for multiple declaration of `Foo::someSignal`. There's one definition in this file, and another in the moc-generated source.