# connect pure-virtual SIGNAL of an abstract class to a SLOT from constructor

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, signals-slots

I have an abstract class that contains the pure virtual signal and a class derived from qobject. Now I want to connect that signal to derived class's
slot. Please see the following code to be clear:

msys.h

```
class MSys : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MSys(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~MSys() {}

public slots:
    void onRequset();
};
```

absview.h

```
class AbsView
{
protected:
    AbsView() : m_sys(new MSys)
    {
        // QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(request()), m_sys, SLOT(onRequset()));
        /* What can I do here !? */
    }

public:
    virtual ~AbsView() {}

signals:
    virtual void request() = 0;

private:
    MSys *m_sys;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(AbsView, "AbsView")
```

Thanks for your time.

Edit: My question just been marked as duplicate comparing with the question that says " [***Declare*** abstract signal in interface class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943496/declare-abstract-signal-in-interface-class) ". But I think that my question clearly says that ***connect*** abstract signal to a slot.

Comment: why do you make a signal virtual?

Comment: @user3528438    So the derived class must have the signal to be a non-abstract class.

Comment: Makes no sense to declare the signal as pure virtual. Is it compiling?

Comment: @BЈовић Sure It does without QObject::connect