# Connection of pure virtual signal of interface class

Tags: qt, c++11

I want to connect some object's signals derived from an interface class.
The connection is done in `QWidget::listenToAnimal(AnimalInterface*)`.
This does not work because `qt_metacall is not a member of 'AnimalInterface'` and `static assertion failed: No Q_OBJECT in the class with the signal`.

Of course `AnimalInterface` does not have the Q_OBJECT macro  and does not inherit QObject because it is an interface...

I want to connect through the interface class because I do not want to manually retype the same code for `Cat` and for `Dog`.

Is it possible to connect the signal the way I want to? Perhaps with templates? Is this perhaps a `lambda`-specific problem?

header:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class AnimalInterface{
public:
    virtual ~AnimalInterface();

    virtual void makeSound() = 0;

/*signals*/
    virtual void madeSound() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(AnimalInterface,"interface")



class Dog : public QObject, public AnimalInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(AnimalInterface)
public:
    void makeSound();
signals:
    void madeSound();
};


class Cat : public QObject, public AnimalInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(AnimalInterface)
public:
    void makeSound();
signals:
    void madeSound();
};



class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Cat *cat_;
    Dog *dog_;
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
    void listenToAnimal(AnimalInterface *animal);
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QDebug>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    dog_ = new Dog;
    cat_ = new Cat;

    listenToAnimal(dog_);
    listenToAnimal(cat_);

    dog_->makeSound();
    cat_->makeSound();
}

void Widget::listenToAnimal(AnimalInterface *animal)
{
    connect(animal, &AnimalInterface::madeSound,
            this,
            [](){
                qDebug()<<"animal made sound";
            });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}


void Cat::makeSound()
{
    qDebug()<<"Cat says miaow";
    emit madeSound();
}
void Dog::makeSound()
{
    qDebug()<<"Dog says wuff";
    emit madeSound();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the derived type at compile type, you can connect to the proper, statically-known `QObject`-derived type. No need for dynamic casting or anything of the sort. You just don't want the `listenToAnimal` method to be available for non-`AnimalInterface`-inheriting types, though, even if it they have a compatible `madeSound` method:

#### C++11

```
#include <type_traits>

template< class T,
          typename = 
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<AnimalInterface, T>::value>::type >
void listenToAnimal(T * animal) {
  connect(animal, &T::madeSound, this, []{ qDebug() << "animal made sound"; });
}
```

#### C++03

```
template <class T>
void listenToAnimal(T * animal) {
  Q_UNUSED(static_cast<AnimalInterface*>(animal));
  connect(animal, &T::madeSound, this, &Widget::onAnimalMadeSound);
}
```

You can then use it without having to spell out the type - it's already known to the compiler:

```
listenToAnimal(dog_);
listenToAnimal(cat_);
```

If the derived type is not known at compile time, you have to dynamically cast to `QObject` and connect by name, not by method pointer. It will assert at runtime if you've passed in a wrong type - after all, it's not enough for it to be an instance of `AnimalInterface`, it also needs to be a `QObject` instance.

```
void listenToAnimal(AnimalInterface * animal) {
  auto object = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(animal);
  Q_ASSERT(object);
  connect(object, SIGNAL(madeSound()), this, SLOT(onAnimalMadeSound()));
}
```

The fact that the type `AnimalInterface` has a virtual `madeSound` method is somewhat relevant - it guarantees that the derived class implements the method with such a signature. It doesn't guarantee that the method is a signal, though. So you should probably rethink your design and ask yourself: "What do I gain by using a static type system when I can't really use it for static type checking"?

Most likely you should make any methods that would nominally accept the `AnimalInterface*`, be parametrized and take a pointer to the concrete class. Modern code generators and linkers will deduplicate such code if type erasure leads to identical machine code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, learned something new, but don't you need to remove the `=` after `typename`? Besides, I get the error `no matching function for call to 'Widget::listenToAnimal(Dog*&)'` when I call `listenToAnimal(dog_)`. And as follow up question, do I need to add `std::is_base<AnimalInterface, T>::value` to the `enable_if` clause, when I construct `Dog` and `Cat` like `AnimalInterface *cat = new Cat`?

Comment: There was a typename missing. Yes, you need `typename = typename ...`, where the first typename is an anonymous template argument. Both forms compile and work as expected.

Comment: Okay now it does compile. I added a last question in my updated answer. Is it possible to connect the signal by passing a pointer to `AnimalInterface` instead of derived class? According to your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943496/declare-abstract-signal-in-interface-class I would say it is not possible, right?

Comment: @user2366975: that's a separate question. Please limit to one question per post.

Comment: @user2366975 It is possible of course, but you have to use RTTI.

Comment: @user2366975 You should edit the question to clarify what you're after and remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with templates. Did not work the first time I tried, obviously did something wrong first. Here it goes...

Just replace the corresponding parts from the example in the question (and remove definition of `listenToAnimal` from the source file):

header:

```
template<class T>
void listenToAnimal(AnimalInterface *animal)
    {
        T *animal_derivate = dynamic_cast<T*>(animal);
        if (animal_derivate){
            connect(animal_derivate, &T::madeSound,
                    this,
                    [](){
                        qDebug()<<"animal made sound";
                    });
        }
    }
```

cpp:

```
listenToAnimal<Dog>(dog_);
listenToAnimal<Cat>(cat_);
```

**Update:**

After trying Kuba Ober's answer, it seems like this is working best now:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<AnimalInterface, T>::value,void>::type
listenToAnimal(T *animal)
    {
        connect(animal, &T::madeSound, this, [](){ qDebug()<<"animal made sound"; });
    }
```

However, the one point still not working is how to connect if I create an animal like `AnimalInterface *bird = new Bird`, because it throws the same error that the base class does not have the signal.