# Declaring signals in interface class using Qt plugin system with new signal-slot syntax

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt5, qtplugin

I'm building a set of plugins for a Qt application, using the [low-level Qt plugin API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications). A manager object will load these plugins at runtime, and allow client programs access to any that are available. I'd like the manager to communicate with the plugin classes via signals and slots, since these plugins may live in different threads than the manager.

So the interface that each plugin must implement should declare these signals and slots. The slots are no problem, because they're really just abstract member functions that each plugin must implement. The signals are the problem.

While the signals can be declared in the interface class, their definition is auto-generated by Qt's `moc` during the compilation process. Thus I can define these signals in the interface class, but when creating a plugin which implements the interface, the build fails at link. This is because the definition of the signals is in the *interface* object file, not the *plugin* object file.

***So the question is***, how can I be sure that the auto-generated implementations of the signals defined in the `Interface` class are generated and/or linked when building the `Plugin` class?

Here is a minimal, complete example to demonstrate the problem.

**Directory structure**

```
test
  |_ test.pro
  |_ app
      |_ app.pro
      |_ interface.h
      |_ main.cc
  |_ plugin
      |_ plugin.pro
      |_ plugin.h
```

**In `test.pro`:**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = app plugin
```

**In `app/app.pro`:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += testlib
HEADERS = interface.h
SOURCES = main.cc
TARGET = test-app
DESTDIR = ../
```

**In `app/interface.h`:**

```
#ifndef _INTERFACE_H_
#define _INTERFACE_H_

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class Interface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        virtual ~Interface() {}

        // Slot which should cause emission of `name` signal.
        virtual void getName() = 0;

    signals:
        // Signal to be emitted in getName()
        void name(QString);
};

#define InterfaceIID "interface"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(Interface, InterfaceIID)

#endif
```

**In `app/main.cc`:**

```
#include "interface.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QSignalSpy>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Find plugin which implements the interface
    Interface* interface;
    QDir dir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    dir.cd("plugins");
    for (auto& filename : dir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
        QPluginLoader loader(dir.absoluteFilePath(filename));
        auto* plugin = loader.instance();
        if (plugin) {
            interface = qobject_cast<Interface*>(plugin);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!interface) {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't load interface!";
        return 0;
    }

    // Verify plugin emits its `name` with `QSignalSpy`.
    QSignalSpy spy(interface, &Interface::name);
    QTimer::singleShot(100, interface, &Interface::getName);
    spy.wait();
    if (spy.count() == 1) {
        auto name = spy.takeFirst().at(0).toString();
        qDebug() << "Plugin emitted name:" << name;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Not emitted!";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

**In `plugin/plugin.h`:**

```
#ifndef _PLUGIN_H_
#define _PLUGIN_H_

#include "interface.h"

class Plugin : public Interface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "interface")
    Q_INTERFACES(Interface)

    public:
        // Override abstract function to emit the `name` signal
        void getName() override { emit name("plugin"); }
};

#endif
```

**In `plugin/plugin.pro`:**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += plugin
INCLUDEPATH += ../app
HEADERS = plugin.h
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(plugin)
DESTDIR = ../plugins
```

This can be compiled by calling `qmake && make` from the top-level directory.

As is, `Interface` inherits from `QObject`, so that it can define the signal that all plugins share. But when compiling the `plugin` subdirectory, we get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Interface::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)", referenced from:
  Plugin::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in moc_plugin.o
"Interface::qt_metacast(char const*)", referenced from:
  Plugin::qt_metacast(char const*) in moc_plugin.o
"Interface::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
  Plugin::staticMetaObject in moc_plugin.o
"Interface::name(QString)", referenced from:
  Plugin::getName() in moc_plugin.o
"typeinfo for Interface", referenced from:
  typeinfo for Plugin in moc_plugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This makes sense to me. The `moc` implements the signal `Interface::name(QString)`, so the implementation and its related symbols are in `moc_interface.o`. That object file is neither compiled nor linked when building the `plugin` sub-directory, so there is no definition of the symbols and the link fails.

I can actually fix this pretty easily, either by including the following line in the `plugin.pro` file:

```
LIBS += ../app/moc_interface.o
```

Or adding:

```
#include "moc_interface.cpp"
```

to the end of `plugin/plugin.h`.

Both of these seem like a bad idea, since these files are automatically generated during the build of `app`, and there's no real way for me to guarantee that they exist. I'd prefer that the writer of a new plugin only need to worry about including the `"interface.h"` header, and not these auto-generated files.

So the question is, how can I get `qmake` to include the definitions of the signals from the `Interface` class when building the `Plugin`?

**Related questions:**

I know that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943699/1354854) solves a closely related problem. But that uses the old-style "stringified" version of connecting signals and slots. I'd prefer to use the new, pointer-to-member syntax, which offers compile-time checks. Also, that solution requires `dynamic_cast`ing the interface, which is more error-prone and less efficient than having the `Interface` class just inherit directly from `QObject`.

Comment: If you don't want to use libraries shared between the plugins and the application, then the interfaces need to be abstract. The signals can be virtual too - it'll work just fine. The modern call syntax will work as long as you hack around the `QObject` class check in `QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro`. It's easy to work around - just add a dummy, empty `qt_metacall` to the interface. :)

Comment: Yeah, MOC is complicated enough without trying to hack around it :). I assume your first comment about shared libraries is the idea behind the solution proposed by @eyllanesc, is that right?

Comment: Yes. There's no need to throw libraries at the problem. Literally make all methods virtual and abstract add one method: `virtual int qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void **) = 0;` - that's the one that makes check macros treat the interface as if it was a `QObject` even though it isn't :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main mistake is that you are combining projects that have circular dependencies.

I have restructured your project using the following structure:

```
test
├── test.pro
├── App
│   ├── App.pro
│   └── main.cpp
├── InterfacePlugin
│   ├── interfaceplugin_global.h
│   ├── interfaceplugin.h
│   └── InterfacePlugin.pro
└──Plugin
    ├── plugin_global.h
    ├── plugin.h
    └── Plugin.pro
```

In it we see that the Interface is an independent library. App and Plugin are 2 projects that use it.

The complete project can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50516359).

Comment: This definitely solves the problem, thanks! Can you explain what's circular about the structure I tried? There's no circularity to the inheritance, so do you mean the interface and plugin libraries are somehow pointing to each other?

Comment: @bnaecker 
Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: @eyllanesc Why did you miss CONFIG  += plugin in the Plugin.pro and why missed slot keyword in the interfaceplugin.h ?

Comment: @DenysRogovchenko 1) Why do you think it is necessary to `CONFIG += plugin`? 2) because I have not created any slots

Comment: @eyllanesc 1) Well, qt uses it on examples such as "Plug & Paint Extra Filters", etc... 2) As I see you call - QTimer::singleShot(...), where substitute &Interface::getName, so getName() should be declared as virtual slot as I understand. Also Qt docs says: 
QTimer::singleShot This static function calls a slot after a given time interval....