How to properly inherit from multiple interfaces which declare signals and slots in Qt 6
I want to have two different interface classes that declare signals and pure virtual slots, and have a implementation class that implements both of them and thus inherits their individual signals and slots. Later on in my code, I want to create an object of Implementation class and pass it around as pointer to interface classes and connect signals and slots to it and I expect the Implementation class's implemented slots to be called.
Something like this:
#include <QObject>

class Interface1
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface1(){}
signals:
    virtual void somethingHappened1() = 0;
public slots:
    virtual void doSomething1() = 0;
}

class Interface2
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface2(){}
signals:
    virtual void somethingHappened2() = 0;
public slots:
    virtual void doSomething2() = 0;
}

Then write the implementation like this:
class Implementation : public QObject, public Interface1, public Interface2
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void somethingHappened1() override;
    void somethingHappened2() override;
public slots:
    void doSomething1() override
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
    void doSomething2() override 
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}

However, this only works in my Qt 5 .pro project. in Qt 6, and in my case Qt 6.6.2 CMake QML projects, writing this gives a warning in the interface classes saying that I cannot have virtual signals in my code and an error message in interface classes saying that "classes that declare signals and slots must have the Q_OBJECT macro"
Which upon doing as it says, leads to another error message saying that if I include Q_OBJECT macro in the interface class then it should also inherit from QObject otherwise it doesn't work.
Which then upon doing as it says, leads to the diamond inheritance error message for QObject!
So, is this feature removed in Qt 6 or am I missing something?
How can we have interfaces that define signals and slots and then implement them in Qt?
Edit: Using Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE and Q_INTERFACES macros do not solve this problem, as they only allow the qobject casts to properly call the methods; The problem is that I can't inherit from the interfaces to begin with.
Edit: See this post. it is exactly what I'm trying to do, but it no longer works

What's the purpose of a virtual signal?  That doesn't make any sense to me.  I also don't understand how moc could successfully parse either of those interface classes and generate any useful code.  Please show the real code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Signals are not supposed to be virtual (and there's no point in doing it). See this post: Virtual Qt signal?. Also, QTBUG-41004.

@G.M. I understand that virtual signal doesn't make sense, but this was how you could declare interfaces with signals in them in Qt 5. I am simply asking how to do the same in Qt 6, and I believe my sample code is clearly explaining what I'm trying to do and why it fails. If you have any particular questions, or if my intention is not clear, please do ask

@musicamante I agree, but this is how you could do it in Qt 5. see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/17943496/17765515

@PunittoMoe That could have been acceptable, but, as the bug report linked above says, signals are not supposed to be virtual. At some point they probably changed something that completely prevents that to begin with.
